# Laravel 4: Where to place upload folder?

Tags: php, laravel-4

In Laravel 4: Where should a not public upload folder be placed? (Best practice)

Where is what comes to mind:

- `\upload`
- `\app\upload`
- `\app\storage\upload`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that

```
/app/storage/uploads
```

is the most appropriate place to store not publicly accessible uploaded files.